# Sending UDP messages between two threads in the same C program (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, networking, udp, pthreads

For a class my group has been assigned to write a program that has two thread, where one thread sends 20 UDP messages to the other thread. The IP address, port numbers, and rate at which the transmit thread sends messages is passed in as command line arguments. When we try to run the program we get the error "sendto failed: Bad Address". We've been trying to figure out why, but we're stumped. We think it has something to do with the recAddr struct. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

const int ipTx = 1, ipRx = 2, portTx = 3, portRx = 4, TxRate = 5;
const int wait_five = 5, num_msgs = 20, wait_ten = 10, wait_twenty = 20;
const int SEC_TO_MILLI = 1000;
int *message;

void *send_msg( void * );
void *receive_msg( void * );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    message = 0;
    pthread_t sendThread, recieveThread;
    int sendFail, recFail;

    sendFail = pthread_create(&sendThread, NULL, send_msg, (void*) argv);
    if(sendFail)
    {
        printf("Error creating send thread\n");
    }

    recFail = pthread_create(&recieveThread, NULL, receive_msg, (void*) argv);
    if(recFail)
    {
        printf("Error creating receive thread\n");
    }

    pthread_join( sendThread, NULL);
    pthread_join( recieveThread, NULL);

    printf("Send thread and receive thread done. Program terminating.\n");

    return 0;
}

void *send_msg( void *argv)
{
    char **args = (char **)argv;
    int sendSocket;
    if((sendSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot create send socket");
        return;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in myAddr;
    memset((char *)&myAddr, 0, sizeof(myAddr));
    myAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(args[ipTx]);
    int port = htons(atoi(args[portTx]));
    myAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (bind(sendSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&myAddr, sizeof(myAddr)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("send socket bind failed");
        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in recAddr;
    memset((char*)&recAddr, 0, sizeof(recAddr));
    recAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    recAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(args[portRx]));
    recAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(args[ipRx]);

    printf("Sleeping for 5 seconds\n");
    sleep(wait_five);

    int sendRate = (intptr_t) args[TxRate];
    sendRate /= SEC_TO_MILLI;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_msgs; i++)
    {
        printf("I am TX and I am going to send a %i\n", message);
        if(sendto(sendSocket, message, sizeof(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recAddr, sizeof(recAddr) ) < 0)
        {
            perror("sendto failed");
            return;
        }
        *message++;
        sleep(sendRate);
    }
    printf("Sleeping for 10 seconds\n");
    sleep(wait_ten);
}

void *receive_msg( void *argv)
{
    const int BUFF_SIZE = 2048;

    char **args = (char **)argv;

    struct sockaddr_in myAddress;
    struct sockaddr_in remoteAddress;
    socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(myAddress);
    int recvLength;
    int receiveSocket;
    unsigned int buf[BUFF_SIZE];

    if((receiveSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot create receive socket\n");
        return;
    }

    memset((char*)&myAddress, 0, sizeof(myAddress));
    myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(args[ipRx]);;
    myAddress.sin_port = htons(atoi(args[portRx]));

    struct timeval rec_timeout;
    rec_timeout.tv_sec = wait_twenty;
    rec_timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    if(setsockopt(receiveSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const void *)&rec_timeout, sizeof(rec_timeout)) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot set timeout option\n");
        return;
    }

    if(bind(receiveSocket, (const struct sockaddr *)&myAddress, sizeof(myAddress)) < 0)
    {
        perror("cannot bind receive socket\n");
        return;
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("waiting on port %d\n", atoi(args[portRx]));
        recvLength = recvfrom(receiveSocket, buf, BUFF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteAddress, &addressLength);
        printf("received %d bytes\n", recvLength);
        if (recvLength > 0)
        {
            buf[recvLength] = 0;
            printf("I am RX and I got a \"%d\"\n", buf);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code in script file we use:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -pthread -o prototype1.out prototype1.c
./prototype1.out 137.104.21.4 137.104.21.4 7084 7085 50
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd look at: `int port = htons(atoi(args[portTx]));` followed by `myAddr.sin_port = htons(port);`...

Comment: print the info about address passed to inet_addr and port (or debug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sendto(sendSocket, message, sizeof(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recAddr, sizeof(recAddr) )
```

The problem here is that `message` is NULL.

This pointer is

1) Initialized to a NULL. The second argument to sendto() should point to valid memory at least the size given by the third argument.

2) The code assumes that this pointer is initialized to at least `sizeof(message)` bytes worth of memory.

Comment: not to mention `*message++` would cause a segmentation fault later on.